# X-server crashes when using the pen on graphics tablet

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, xserver, graphics-tablet

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I got a new XP-Pen Deco01 V2 drawing tablet. It connects fine, but as soon as I try to move the cursor using the drawing pen, the x server crashes.

Any clues as to how to fix this??

/var/log/syslog:

```
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) libinput: UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet: needs a virtual subdevice
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (**) UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0): Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0)'
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event259 13:259
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (**) UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0): always reports core events
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event259"
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) libinput: UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0): is a virtual subdevice
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (EE) Too many input devices. Ignoring UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0)
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (II) systemd-logind: not releasing fd for 13:259, still in use
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra blueman-tray[21419]: blueman-tray: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra blueman-applet[21329]: blueman-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra at-spi-bus-launcher[21098]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra redshift-gtk[21316]: redshift-gtk: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra pulseaudio[20755]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra evolution-alarm[21319]: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-wacom[21251]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-keyboard[21233]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-xsettings[21259]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra update-notifier[22071]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-media-keys[21234]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-power[21235]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Stopped target GNOME Wacom handling.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra bluetoothd[1536]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.342 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra bluetoothd[1536]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.342 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gsd-color[21230]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra acpid: client 20807[0:0] has disconnected
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gnome-terminal-[21460]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-media-keys.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-media-keys.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-wacom.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-wacom.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Stopped GNOME Wacom handling.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-wacom.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-keyboard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-keyboard.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Stopped target GNOME Keyboard handling.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Stopped target GNOME Media keys handling.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Stopped target GNOME Power management handling.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra gnome-shell[21045]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Started GNOME Session Failed lockdown screen (user).
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: Reached target GNOME Session Failed.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-color.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gsd-color.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 00:13:39 Lyra systemd[2742]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

*UPDATE:* Due to the log line
`May 28 00:13:39 Lyra /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20807]: (EE) Too many input devices. Ignoring UGTABLET 10 inch PenTablet Pen (0)`

After disconnecting the web cam to reduce the number of input devices, it works correctly.

Is there a better way to fix this ?

Comment: Are you really *logged out*? Or is your desktop *crashing*? Check your /var/crash file and your /var/log/syslog.

Comment: @user535733 It was the desktop crashing.

Comment: The crash was due to too many input devices, the tab is working alright after disconnecting webcam. Leaving the question open for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of input devices was increased from 40 to 256 in xorg-server version 1.20.10, which should let you use the tablet and webcam at the same time. The main focal repository only has 1.20.9, but 1.20.11 is available from the focal-updates repository (as of 2021-09-20).